# SPDLib spdinterp Error: Two file paths should have been specified (e.g., Input and Output)

Tags: lidar, mac, spdlib, spdinterp

I am using [`spdinterp`](http://www.spdlib.org/doku.php?id=spdlib:users:commands:spdinterp) from the [SPDlib](http://www.spdlib.org/doku.php?id=spdlib:users:commands:spdinterp) to produce a digital terrain model using the following command:

```
spdinterp --dtm --topo -r 50 -c 50 --overlap 10 -i NATURAL_NEIGHBOR -f HFA -b 1 /Users/aaron/data/1158-30-46.spd /Users/aaron/data/1158-30-46_dtm_1m.img
```

Which yields the following error:

```
0: -r
1: 50
2: -c
3: 50
4: -f
5: HFA
6: -b
7: 1
8: /Users/aaron/data/1158-30-46.spd
9: /Users/aaron/data/1158-30-46_dtm_1m.img
Error: Two file paths should have been specified (e.g., Input and Output). 10 were provided.
```

Clearly, two file paths were included in the command. "10 were provided" is quite puzzling.

I'm running the binary version of SPDLib for Mac OS. How can I resolve this error?

edit:

When I set the `-i` and `-o` switches, the `-i` switch appears to conflict with the `-i` interpolator switch. I get the following error:

```
PARSE ERROR: Argument: -i (--interpolator)
             Argument already set!
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the input and output files with the switches -i and -o.

See the help documentation: spdinterp --help

```
spdinterp --dtm --topo -r 50 -c 50 --overlap 10 -i NATURAL_NEIGHBOR -f HFA -b 1 -i /Users/aaron/data/1158-30-46.spd -o /Users/aaron/data/1158-30-46_dtm_1m.img
```

This is a bug with this release in that I left some options I was experimenting within the command line interface for `spdinterp` so you should use `NATURAL_NEIGHBOR_CGAL` rather than `NATURAL_NEIGHBOR`.

Comment: Thanks Pete. When I set the `-i` and `-o` switches, the `-i` switch appears to conflict with the `-i` interpolator switch. I get the following error: `PARSE ERROR: Argument: -i (--interpolator)
             Argument already set!`, Also, it appears that my mac binary version does not support `NATURAL_NEIGHBOR_CGAL` as I get the following error: `PARSE ERROR: Argument: -i (--interpolator)
             Value 'NATURAL_NEIGHBOR_CGAL' does not meet constraint: TIN_PLANE|NEAREST_NEIGHBOR|NATURAL_NEIGHBOR|STDEV_MULTISCALE|TPS_RAD|TPS_PTNO`